# How to send only two column values from jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, click, send

I have a jqgrid and on button click I just want to send two column values instead of sending the whole values...how can I achieve is using getRowData ....any suggestion will be appreciated..
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the method [getCol](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) can halt you mostly. If one from the columns which you want to send is the column with `id` (`key:true`) then you can receive data which you need with one call:

```
var myData = $('#list').jqGrid('getCol', 'column Name 1', true);
```

If no from the columns has `key:true` in the column definition you should make two calls:

```
var myData1 = $('#list').jqGrid('getCol', 'column Name 1');
var myData2 = $('#list').jqGrid('getCol', 'column Name 2');
```

Then you can combine the data or set there separate as two parameters:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/cpsb/internalOrderList.do",
    data : {
        jgGridData1: JSON.stringify(myData1),
        jgGridData2: JSON.stringify(myData2)
    },
    dataType:"json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```